# ASP.NET Web.config encryption - temp files can't be accessed

Tags: asp.net, encryption, web-config

I have an asp.net application.
There are secret parts contained in the web.config file which I want to protect through encryption.
I'm using the ConfigurationSection.SectionInformation.ProtectSection method and later using WebConfigurationManager.Save to save it.
Locally it works OK.

The problems is when it runs on the server, I get this error:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred loading a configuration file: (C:\Inetpub\vhosts(SiteName)\httpdocs\web.config) ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Inetpub\vhosts(SiteName)\httpdocs\rz0fkykb.tmp' is denied.

This problems seems to take place because there is no write permission for the temp file which is obviously being created as part of encrypting the parts in web.config. I don't know the name of the temp file to be created and I don't want to give total write permission to the whole basic directory (security).

Is there a way to configure the path or the name of the tmp file created as side effect of the web.config encryption so I can isolate it and give to it (or to the custom specific directory) writing permissions?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx   
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/01/08/encrypting-custom-configuration-sections.aspx   
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/09/434893.aspx

Answer (score 1):

at the webconfig file set under the `<system.web>` this code

```
 <identity impersonate="true" userName="your username of your current account"
        password="your  password" />
```

Comment: Even if it will solve the problem, it will give write permission for the application for all the files. 
I want to limit the write permission for writing the tmp files only.